# ArrayList failed to remove Character

Tags: java, list, arraylist, integer, character

I am trying to remove one Character in my ArrayList. But I always have to build a object to remove, why cannot I remove like the way I add Character?

```
List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add('z');
list.add('x');
list.add('y');
System.out.println("TEST1: " + list);
Character g = new Character('x');
list.remove(g);
System.out.println("TEST2: " + list);
list.remove('y');

The last line gives me these errors:

TEST1: [z, x, y]
TEST2: [z, y]
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 121, Size: 2
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:492)
```

The Java doc here shows:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-java.lang.Object-

```
boolean        add(E e)
               Appends the specified element to the end of this list.
boolean        remove(Object o)
               Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present.
```

Comment: Because you end up calling `remove(int index)`

Comment: Compiler has to decide which method to call at *compile time*

Comment: So, you mean, compiler transfer 'y' into the ASCII value and treat it as a int?

Comment: Yes. See Neng Liu's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ArrayList` has two implemention for `remove`:

- `public boolean remove(Object o)`
- `public E remove(int index)`

When you call it by:

```
list.remove(Character)
```

you are calling

```
public boolean remove(Object o)
```

so it can success.

But when you call it by:

```
list.remove('y');
```

the `char y` will be converted to `int 121`(try this `System.out.println((int) 'y');`), you are implictly calling

```
public E remove(121)
```

thats why you get `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the valueOf() method of the Character class to achieve this,

```
list.remove(Character.valueOf('x'));
```

For your called method for the removal of object from list,its Alreday explained by the Neng Liu ,its getting converted in to int.